# No owner defined between domain classes

Tags: grails, many-to-many, grails-domain-class

Currently i'm getting the following error :

```
No owner defined between domain classes [class mp.ra.Classgroup] and [class mp.ra.Event] in a many-to-many relationship.
```

The domain classes are set up as followed,
The event class:

```
class Event {
static hasMany = [classgroups:Classgroup]
static belongsTo = [eventgroup:Eventgroup,classgroup:Classgroup]

static constraints = {
    eventgroup nullable:true
}
```

And the Classgroup

```
class Classgroup {

static hasMany = [courses:Course,events:Event]

static constraints = {
    courses nullable:true
}
```

An Event can have multiple classgroups and a classgroup can have multiple events. 
I use the belongs to property so i don't see why i'm getting this error.

EDIT: I changed The Event class and the error is gone , i dont know if this is a good solution

```
class Event {

Eventgroup eventgroup


static hasMany = [classgroups:Classgroup]
static belongsTo = [Eventgroup, Classgroup]

static constraints = {
    eventgroup nullable:true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Grails many-to-many mapping we should define an owner class between both of the associated classes.
As earlier you defined :

```
belongsTo = [eventgroup:Eventgroup,classgroup:Classgroup]
```

with this GORM tried to create a column with classgroup name under Event table, but for many-to-many association with classgroup, database should suppose to have third table to have multiple records for many-to-many associations between Event and Classgroup. So was giving such error.

Hence later when you mention :

```
belongsTo = [Eventgroup, Classgroup]
```

it worked as it just got owner information. 
So here Classgroup would be the owner of association, as Event belongsTo Classgroup.

Hope this helps. Thanks.